# Python : storing data to text file

Tags: python

I have printed this data and would like to convert this data to a text file using Python. How do I do that?

A1 21 10 1

A2 10 11 0

A3 12 13 9

Comment: I received an error saying "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None".

Comment: Please [edit] to show how you are getting this data and how you attempted to write it to a file (ex. what exactly did you pass to `write()`?)

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation of file I/O is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). There is also a friendly tutorial you can access [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm).

Once you read these and try and make something, you can refine and focus your question to make it answerable in a more specific way.

Comment: To me, this answer should most likely be posted as a comment as it does not directly answer the question.

Comment: @mad - you are right, in more ways than one. The reason I made this an answer is to demonstrate how a generic question receives a generic answer, and also because of the support for formatting links. I was hoping that this would be a better approach than to slap the question with a dowqvote. If you still disagree with this reasoning, let me know, and I will convert the answer to a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write to a text file, assuming this data is coming from another file :

```
with open("sourcefile.txt") as f1, open("destfile.txt", "w") as f2:
    for line in f1:
        f2.write(line)
```

This is in the case data is coming from one file and you are writing to another file.

And if the data is coming from a console than this would be sufficient to write it to a file :

```
 python source.py > destfile.txt
```

`Note you are using this operator when executing your python code via the console!`

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. However, this data is coming when I printed out in the console. so I would like to write this data to file.

Comment: I edited the answer and left the previous section for benefit of other people !

Comment: @Hanna Does this not answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open("dest.txt", "w") as file: # w access mode is needed so you can write to a file
 file.write("A1 21 10 1 \n"); # newline needed because file.write doesn't add it automatically
 ...
 ...
```